# How to open a program with cmd.exe from Python?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cmd, gis

I am using python 3.3 and in my code I need something to open cmd.exe with the following arguments and run it. The desired line in cmd.exe should be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GlobalMapper15>global_mapper.exe script.gms variable
```

I saw different answers but the most I managed with subprocess.call is to open either cmd.exe, or global_mapper.exe. I did not manage to obtain the line above in cmd.exe.

I tried so far:

```
#import subprocess
import os
os.system("cmd.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\GlobalMapper15\global_mapper.exe script.gms")
#subprocess.call(["cmd.exe C:\Program Files (x86)\GlobalMapper15\global_mapper.exe", "script.gms"])
```

Neither of them worked well.

Of course, it would be great if the line would be also executed. Can anyone help me make this happen?

Thank you all,

Comment: _"the most I managed with subprocess.call is to open either cmd.exe, or global_mapper.exe."_ I would be interested in seeing this code.

Comment: @Kevin
well, you can test that even by running something as simple as:

    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["cmd.exe"])

This opens cmd.exe. It is not enough though, I still need to add all the extra arguments on the line.

Comment: maybe this can help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: What happened when you tried adding all the extra arguments to `subprocess.call`? So far, you haven't posted any code, so it looks like you're just asking us to write your project for you.

Comment: @EduardoPino Thank you, I tried to follow that code but I got stuck. I will keep trying.

Comment: @Kevin I am asking for some help in doing this. I already posted the basic usage that opens one or the other. I tried subprocess.call(["cmd.exe", "C:\Program Files (x86)\GlobalMapper15\global_mapper.exe script.gms"]) but it opens only cmd.exe with the following line: C:\Python33> I am trying to learn it step by stem since I am a newby. I asked because I tried for a few hours and I got stuck, not because I want you to write this for me. Some of the examples out there are too hard to understand for now

Comment: @Robert: don't post the code in the comments. [Update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21882553/edit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run `global_mapper.exe` in given directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import call

dir = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\GlobalMapper15"
cmdline = "global_mapper.exe script.gms variable"
rc = call(cmdline, cwd=dir) # run `cmdline` in `dir`
```

If you want to start the command in a new console window:

```
rc = call("start cmd /K " + cmdline, cwd=dir, shell=True)
```

Comment: Many thanks for making it clear. I understand now how it works. Geez, programming can really speed things up. 

Thanks to all,

Answer (score 2):

maybe with this:

```
import os
os.system("program.exe -parameter")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can Create a .bat file and call it

```
dir = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\GlobalMapper15"
write=''.join((dir,'\\','call.bat'))
f= open(write,'w')
with f:
  f.write('@ECHO ON\n Call global_mapper.exe script.gms variable'
subprocess.call(write,cwd=dir)
```

Comment: If you need to do this in Program Files folders, you will likely run into adminstrator permission issues. Otherwise, in a user home or appdata folder, this could work well.